# QGIS crashes when digitizing new fetaures

Tags: qgis, windows-7, 64bit

I can't currently digitize polygon features in QGIS 2.01 or 2.3. 
I can draw a set of points but as soon as I right click to finish the system crashes. It still works fine in 1.8.

Windows 7 64

Comment: Can you activate debug messages like described here:http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-see-log-debug-messages-in-Osgeo4W-installer-qgis-dev-td5047542.html ?

Comment: [3840] ..\..\..\..\..\src\core\qgsgeometryvalidator.cpp(324) : (QgsGeometryValidator::run) validation finished.
[3840] ..\..\..\..\..\src\app\qgsmaptooladdfeature.cpp(68) : (QgsMapToolAddFeature::canvasReleaseEvent) entered.
[3840] ..\..\..\..\..\src\app\qgsfeatureaction.cpp(156) : (QgsFeatureAction::addFeature) reuseLastValues: 0
[4344] CCM: InitializeCOM: CoInitializeEx() returned RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE.
[5256] CCM: InitializeCOM: CoInitializeEx() returned RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE.

Comment: Hopefully that shows what is happening

Comment: Are you using the 32 or 64 bit version of QGIS? Have you tried reinstalling with a redownloaded file?

Comment: Unfortunately, the debug lines don't help me further. If 32bit fails too, I suggest to create a bug report at hub.qgis.org to let the developers look over the debug messages.

Comment: I am using 64 bit version, you should be able to digitize features really?? that's a pretty basic function, like being able to read jpegs - oh wait!

Comment: Downloaded the fresh version 2.2 64bit doesn't work 32bit does - so I guess I have to use the 32 bit version